# Sybase SQL Anywhere 16 SAConnection.Close() exception

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

I've run this application a million times...

Today I'm testing my application on a new PC and get an exception error everytime the code runs the SAConnection.Close() command.

This is what I'm doing...

```
SAConnection dbConn = new SAConnection(m_cnBuilder.ConnectionString);
            dbConn.Open();

            if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Connection successful", "Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            dbConn.Close();
```

Not rocket science.  The error comes on the last line.  Can anyone help me with this?

The error I get is:

> SQL Anywhere .NET data provider: Run time SQL
>   error -- ??? (-300)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code -300 suggests you executed some SQL and that there is an error in the SQL.

> -300 Run time SQL error -- %1 
>   An internal database error occurred. If it can be reproduced, it should be reported to iAnywhere. You may be able to work around this problem by modifying the associated query statement.

Comment: Interesting...does this suggest either reinstalling synapse?  Or do you think I'm stuck?  Btw.as you can see above I'm not executing a query, just checking that I can establish a db connection.

Comment: perhaps there is a trigger or procedure set in the DB to execute SQL on connect or disconnect.

Comment: Sorry. Checked no trigger or SP. I do agree that it's a db problem.

Comment: Could it be a .NET issue?

Comment: @beater...We were able to reinstall our Sybase and now everything works.  Since you are the only person to respond, I'm giving you all the credit.  Thanks for your help!